# Pass a data.frame column name to a function

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

I'm trying to write a function to accept a data.frame (`x`) and a `column` from it. The function performs some calculations on x and later returns another data.frame. I'm stuck on the best-practices method to pass the column name to the function.

The two minimal examples `fun1` and `fun2` below produce the desired result, being able to perform operations on `x$column`, using `max()` as an example. However, both rely on the seemingly (at least to me) inelegant

1. call to `substitute()` and possibly `eval()`
2. the need to pass the column name as a character vector.

```
fun1 <- function(x, column){
  do.call("max", list(substitute(x[a], list(a = column))))
}

fun2 <- function(x, column){
  max(eval((substitute(x[a], list(a = column)))))
}

df <- data.frame(B = rnorm(10))
fun1(df, "B")
fun2(df, "B")
```

I would like to be able to call the function as `fun(df, B)`, for example. Other options I have considered but have not tried:

- Pass `column` as an integer of the column number. I think this would avoid `substitute()`. Ideally, the function could accept either.
- `with(x, get(column))`, but, even if it works, I think this would still require `substitute`
- Make use of `formula()` and `match.call()`, neither of which I have much experience with.

*Subquestion*: Is `do.call()` preferred over `eval()`?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can just use the column name directly:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12)
fun1 <- function(x, column){
  max(x[,column])
}
fun1(df, "B")
fun1(df, c("B","A"))
```

There's no need to use substitute, eval, etc.

You can even pass the desired function as a parameter:

```
fun1 <- function(x, column, fn) {
  fn(x[,column])
}
fun1(df, "B", max)
```

Alternatively, using `[[` also works for selecting a single column at a time:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12)
fun1 <- function(x, column){
  max(x[[column]])
}
fun1(df, "B")
```

Comment: Is there any way to pass the column name not as a string?

Comment: You need to either pass the column name quoted as a character or the integer index for the column.  Just passing `B` will assume that B is an object itself.

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how I ended up with the convoluted substitute, eval, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for the max value of all the values from a vector "B" that's contained in another vector "A"?  Or are you looking to apply a function to a set of columns from a data frame?

Comment: The function actually has nothing to do with max. It was just what came to mind when I was trying to write an example.

Comment: You could also look on the `subset.data.frame` code and see how is column selection done.

Comment: Thanks! I found the `[[` solution was the only one that worked for me.

Comment: I ´m still unsure when using [] and when using [[]]. @EcologyTom Do you know the difference?

Comment: Hi @Luis, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-elem)

Answer (score 160):

This answer will cover many of the same elements as existing answers, but this issue (passing column names to functions) comes up often enough that I wanted there to be an answer that covered things a little more comprehensively.

Suppose we have a very simple data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = 1:4,
                  y = 5:8)
```

and we'd like to write a function that creates a new column `z` that is the sum of columns `x` and `y`.

A very common stumbling block here is that a natural (but incorrect) attempt often looks like this:

```
foo <- function(df,col_name,col1,col2){
      df$col_name <- df$col1 + df$col2
      df
}

#Call foo() like this:    
foo(dat,z,x,y)
```

The problem here is that `df$col1` doesn't evaluate the expression `col1`. It simply looks for a column in `df` literally called `col1`. This behavior is described in `?Extract` under the section "Recursive (list-like) Objects".

The simplest, and most often recommended solution is simply switch from `$` to `[[` and pass the function arguments as strings:

```
new_column1 <- function(df,col_name,col1,col2){
    #Create new column col_name as sum of col1 and col2
    df[[col_name]] <- df[[col1]] + df[[col2]]
    df
}

> new_column1(dat,"z","x","y")
  x y  z
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
4 4 8 12
```

This is often considered "best practice" since it is the method that is hardest to screw up. Passing the column names as strings is about as unambiguous as you can get.

The following two options are more advanced. Many popular packages make use of these kinds of techniques, but using them *well* requires more care and skill, as they can introduce subtle complexities and unanticipated points of failure. [This](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) section of Hadley's Advanced R book is an excellent reference for some of these issues.

If you *really* want to save the user from typing all those quotes, one option might be to convert bare, unquoted column names to strings using `deparse(substitute())`:

```
new_column2 <- function(df,col_name,col1,col2){
    col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
    col1 <- deparse(substitute(col1))
    col2 <- deparse(substitute(col2))

    df[[col_name]] <- df[[col1]] + df[[col2]]
    df
}

> new_column2(dat,z,x,y)
  x y  z
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
4 4 8 12
```

This is, frankly, a bit silly probably, since we're really doing the same thing as in `new_column1`, just with a bunch of extra work to convert bare names to strings.

Finally, if we want to get *really* fancy, we might decide that rather than passing in the names of two columns to add, we'd like to be more flexible and allow for other combinations of two variables. In that case we'd likely resort to using `eval()` on an expression involving the two columns:

```
new_column3 <- function(df,col_name,expr){
    col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
    df[[col_name]] <- eval(substitute(expr),df,parent.frame())
    df
}
```

Just for fun, I'm still using `deparse(substitute())` for the name of the new column. Here, all of the following will work:

```
> new_column3(dat,z,x+y)
  x y  z
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
4 4 8 12
> new_column3(dat,z,x-y)
  x y  z
1 1 5 -4
2 2 6 -4
3 3 7 -4
4 4 8 -4
> new_column3(dat,z,x*y)
  x y  z
1 1 5  5
2 2 6 12
3 3 7 21
4 4 8 32
```

So the short answer is basically: pass data.frame column names as strings and use `[[` to select single columns. Only start delving into `eval`, `substitute`, etc. if you really know what you're doing.

Comment: What to do if I want to pass columns for tidy select? I want to create a function that used `pivot_longer` .  My function looks like this   `lineplots <- function(df, colname){
  ggplot(data = df %>% pivot_longer(-colname), aes(x = colname, y = value)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales = "free_y")
}'` and its not working as I expect it to

Comment: @NathanStutzman For tidyverse stuff the method they (eventually) settled on was to "embrace" the argument by wrapping it in `{{}}`. See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Answer (score 28):

Personally I think that passing the column as a string is pretty ugly. I like to do something like:

```
get.max <- function(column,data=NULL){
    column<-eval(substitute(column),data, parent.frame())
    max(column)
}
```

which will yield:

```
> get.max(mpg,mtcars)
[1] 33.9
> get.max(c(1,2,3,4,5))
[1] 5
```

Notice how the specification of a data.frame is optional. you can even work with functions of your columns:

```
> get.max(1/mpg,mtcars)
[1] 0.09615385
```

Comment: You need to get out of the habit of thinking using quotes is ugly.  Not using them is ugly! Why? Because you've created a function that can only be used interactively - it's very difficult to program with it.

Comment: I'm happy to be shown a better way, but I fail to see the difference between this and qplot(x=mpg,data=mtcars). ggplot2 never passes a column as a string, and I think it is better off for it. Why do you say that this can only be used interactively? Under what situation would it lead to undesirable results? How is it more difficult to program with? In the body of the post I display how it is more flexible.

Comment: 5 years later -) .. Why do we need: parent.frame() ?

Comment: 7 years later: is not using quotes still ugly?

Answer (score 15):

With `dplyr` it's now also possible to access a specific column of a dataframe  by simply using double curly braces `{{...}}` around the desired column name within the function body, e.g. for `col_name`:

```
library(tidyverse)

fun <- function(df, col_name){
   df %>% 
     filter({{col_name}} == "test_string")
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Another way is to use [`tidy evaluation`](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/) approach. It is pretty straightforward to pass columns of a data frame either as strings or bare column names. See more about `tidyeval` [here](https://maraaverick.rbind.io/2017/08/tidyeval-resource-roundup/).

```r
library(rlang)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(B = rnorm(10), D = rnorm(10))
```

Use column names as strings

```r
fun3 <- function(x, ...) {
  # capture strings and create variables
  dots <- ensyms(...)
  # unquote to evaluate inside dplyr verbs
  summarise_at(x, vars(!!!dots), list(~ max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
}

fun3(df, "B")
#>          B
#> 1 1.715065

fun3(df, "B", "D")
#>          B        D
#> 1 1.715065 1.786913
```

Use bare column names

```r
fun4 <- function(x, ...) {
  # capture expressions and create quosures
  dots <- enquos(...)
  # unquote to evaluate inside dplyr verbs
  summarise_at(x, vars(!!!dots), list(~ max(., na.rm = TRUE)))
}

fun4(df, B)
#>          B
#> 1 1.715065

fun4(df, B, D)
#>          B        D
#> 1 1.715065 1.786913
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54940237/pass-data-frame-columns-as-arguments-to-mutate-function/

Comment: Just what I needed: tidy eval. Newer article: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 3):

[Tung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948070/13048728) and [mgrund's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895032/13048728) presented [tidy evaluation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/tidyeval.html). In this answer I'll show how we can use these concepts to do something similar to [joran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36015931/13048728) (specifically his function `new_column3`). The objective to this is to make it easier to see the differences between base evaluation and tidy one, and also to see the different syntaxes that can be used in tidy evaluation. You will need `rlang` and `dplyr` for this.

Using base evaluation tools (joran's answer):

```
new_column3 <- function(df,col_name,expr){
  col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
  df[[col_name]] <- eval(substitute(expr),df,parent.frame())
  df
}
```

In the first line, `substitute` is making us evaluate `col_name` as an expression, more specifically a symbol (also sometimes called a name), not an object. rlang's substitutes can be:

- `ensym` - turns it into a symbol;
- `enexpr` - turns it into a expression;
- `enquo` - turns it into a quosure, an expression that also points the environment where R should look for the variables to evaluate it.

Most of the time, you want to have that pointer to the environment. When you don't specifically need it, having it rarely causes problems. Thus, most of the time you can use `enquo`. In this case, you can use `ensym` to make the code easier to read, as it makes it clearer what `col_name` is.

Also in the first line, `deparse` is turning the expression/symbol into a string. You could also use `as.character` or `rlang::as_string`.

In the second line, the `substitute` is turning `expr` into a 'full' expression (not a symbol), so `ensym` is not an option anymore.

Also in the second line, we can now change `eval` to `rlang::eval_tidy`. Eval would still work with `enexpr`, but not with a quosure. When you have a quosure, you don't need to pass the environment to the evaluation function (as joran did with `parent.frame()`).

One combination of the substitutions suggested above might be:

```
new_column3 <- function(df,col_name,expr){
  col_name <- as_string(ensym(col_name))
  df[[col_name]] <- eval_tidy(enquo(expr), df)
  df
}
```

We can also use the `dplyr` operators, which allow for data-masking (evaluating a column in a data frame as a variable, calling it by its name). We can change the method of transforming the symbol to character + subsetting `df` using `[[` with `mutate`:

```
new_column3 <- function(df,col_name,expr){
  col_name <- ensym(col_name)
  df %>% mutate(!!col_name := eval_tidy(enquo(expr), df))
}
```

To avoid the new column to be named "col_name", we anxious-evaluate it (as opposed to lazy-evaluate, the default of R) with the bang-bang `!!` operator. Because we made an operation to the left hand side, we can't use 'normal' `=`, and must use the new syntax `:=`.

The common operation of turning a column name into a symbol, then anxious-evaluating it with bang-bang has a shortcut: the curly-curly `{{` operator:

```
new_column3 <- function(df,col_name,expr){
  df %>% mutate({{col_name}} := eval_tidy(enquo(expr), df))
}
```

I'm not an expert in evaluation in R and might have done an over simplification, or used a wrong term, so please correct me in the comments. I hope to have helped in comparing the different tools used in the answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

As an extra thought, if is needed to pass the column name unquoted to the custom function, perhaps `match.call()` could be useful as well in this case, as an alternative to `deparse(substitute())`:

```r
df <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 2:11)

fun <- function(x, column){
  arg <- match.call()
  max(x[[arg$column]])
}

fun(df, A)
#> [1] 10

fun(df, B)
#> [1] 11
```

If there is a typo in the column name, then would be safer to stop with an error:

```r
fun <- function(x, column) max(x[[match.call()$column]])
fun(df, typo)
#> Warning in max(x[[match.call()$column]]): no non-missing arguments to max;
#> returning -Inf
#> [1] -Inf

# Stop with error in case of typo
fun <- function(x, column){
  arg <- match.call()
  if (is.null(x[[arg$column]])) stop("Wrong column name")
  max(x[[arg$column]])
}

fun(df, typo)
#> Error in fun(df, typo): Wrong column name
fun(df, A)
#> [1] 10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I do not think I would use this approach since there is extra typing and complexity than just passing the quoted column name as pointed in the above answers, but well, is an approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build this function within an R package or simply want to reduce complexity, you can do the following:

```
test_func <- function(df, column) {
  if (column %in% colnames(df)) {
    return(max(df[, column, with=FALSE])) 
  } else {
    stop(cat(column, "not in data.frame columns."))
  }
}
```

The argument `with=FALSE` "disables the ability to refer to columns as if they are variables, thereby restoring the “data.frame mode” (per [CRAN documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)). The if statement is a quick way to catch if the column name provided is within the data.frame. Could also use tryCatch error handling here.