# Function in R, passing a dataframe and a column name

Tags: function, r, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function)

I am trying to create a function in R where between the inputs there is dataframe and a column name. The code would be something like this:

```
DT_CAP_COLUMN  <- function(input_table,output_table,column_name,
                           cap_function,Parameter){
  input_table$column_name
  (...)
  return(1)
}
```

Output:

```
DT_CAP_COLUMN(churn_3,churn_4,'VOICE_REVENUE','STD',3)
input_table$column_name is NA
```

I think the problem is that `input_table$column_name` is not recognized. `input_table` is `churn_3` but `input_table$column_name` returns `column_name not found`.

Is there anyway to do this without having to use pass-by-references packages or passing environments as variables?

Comment: @Kevin Good spot.  Voting to close.

Comment: Only because I had the same question...

Comment: No need to downvote a dupe, especially not for a new user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can indirectly reference a column in a data.frame by using square bracket indexing:

Sample data:

```
 dat <- data.frame(
     a = letters[1:3],
     b = LETTERS[4:6],
     c = 7:9
 )
```

Function:

```
 my.function <- function(data, col){
   data[, col]
 }
```

Results:

```
>  my.function(dat, "b" )
  b
1 D
2 E
3 F
>  my.function(dat, "c" )
  c
1 7
2 8
3 9
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Worked exactly as I wanted using both column numbers and column names.