# Write function to plot data, requires passing data.frame column names

Tags: r, function, plot

I would like to write a function to create plots (in order to create multiple plots without listing the design settings every time). The *pirateplot function that I use requires columnnames and a dataframe as input*, which causes problems.

My not-working code is:

```
pirateplot_default <- function(DV,IV,Dataset) {
  plot <- pirateplot(formula = DV ~ IV,
             data = Dataset,
             xlab = "Solution")
  return(plot)
}
```

- I have tried "as.name" (saw that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898596/pass-column-names-to-a-function)) but it did not work.
- using data[DV] is no option because the pirateplot function requires a different notation
- I know that there are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898596/pass-column-names-to-a-function),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310186/function-in-r-passing-a-dataframe-and-a-column-name), and this probably qualifies as duplicate for more skilled programmers, but I did not manage to apply the solutions at other questions to my problem, so hoping for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

```
pirateplot_default <- function(DV,IV,Dataset) {
  tmp=as.formula(paste0(DV,"~",paste0(IV,collapse="+")))
  plot <- pirateplot(formula = tmp,
                     data = Dataset,
                     xlab = "Solution")
  return(plot)
}

pirateplot_default("mpg",c("disp","cyl","hp"),mtcars)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, didn't occur to me that I could manipulate the formula as a whole. Works perfectly. And thank you for adding the flexibility in case there are multiple independent variables (IV).