# Difficulties using `with` inside a function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to understand how to pass a data frame to an R function.  I found an answer to this question on StackOverflow that provides the following demonstration / [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function):

[Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function)

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=2:11, C=3:12)
fun1 <- function(x, column){
  max(x[,column])
}

fun1(df, "B")
fun1(df, c("B","A"))
```

This makes sense to me, but I don't quit understand the rules for calling data frames within a function.  Take the following example:

```
data(iris)
x.test <- function(df, x){ 
  out <- with(df, mean(x))
  return(out)
}    
x.test(iris, "Sepal.Length")
```

The output of this is NA, with a warning message.  But, if I do the same procedure without the function it seems to work just fine.

```
with(iris, mean(Sepal.Length))
```

I'm obviously missing something here -- any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you're passing Sepal.Length in as characters.  The equivalent call would be `with(iris, mean("Sepal.Length"))`

Comment: @Dason:  True, they aren't equivalent, so maybe that wasn't my best phrasing.  I guess I am trying to have the function return the same thing as with(iris, mean(Sepal.Length)).  When I remove the quotation marks, the function returns an error:  "object 'Sepal.Length' not found.

Comment: Why I changed the title: The problem was not in the passage of either the dataframe or the character vector, but with the evaluation inside the function using `with`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been given the correct advice already (which was to use "[" or "[[" rather than `with` inside functions) but it might also be helpful to ponder why the problem occurred. Inside the `with` you asked the `mean` function to return the mean of a character vector, so NA was the result. When you used with at the interactive level, you had no quotes around the character name of the column and if you had you would have gotten the same result:

```
> with(iris, mean('Sepal.Length'))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

If you had used the R `get` mechanism for "promoting" a character object to return the result of a named object you would actually have succeeded, although `with` is still generally not recommended for programming use:

```
x.test <- function(df, x){ 
   out <- with(df, mean( get(x)) )    #  get() retrieves the named object from the workspace
   return(out)
 }    
 x.test(iris, "Sepal.Length")
#[1] 5.843333
```

See the Details section of the `?with` page for warnings about its use in functions.

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation.  A solution was provided, but now I get why `with` was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
data(iris)
x.test <- function(df, x){ 
  out <- mean(df[, x])
  return(out)
}    
x.test(iris, "Sepal.Length")
```

Your code is trying to take `mean("Sepal.Length")` which is clearly not what you want.