# How to store t or F value and P value in data frame

Tags: r

```
x<- c(62, 60, 63, 59, 63, 67, 71, 64, 65, 66, 68, 66, 71, 67, 68, 68, 56, 62, 60, 61, 63, 64, 63, 59)
grp1<- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:2], c(1,2)))
grp2<-rep(1:3)

dat <- data.frame(x,grp1,grp2)

aaa<-function(dset,var,group) {
  if (length(levels(group))==2) {
     ttest<-t.test(dset$var~dat$group)


  }
  else {
     anova<-aov(var~group,data=dset)  


  }
}
```

How to store t or F value and P value in data frame bbb? I hope that results like:
if choose ttest, bbb$stat=t-value,bbb$p<-p-value
if choouse anova,bbb$stat=F-value,bbb$p<-p-value
Thanks!

Comment: can you show us what you've tried so far (rather than just giving specifications and asking for code)?  You'll need `length(levels(grp1))` and `?"if"`; search Stack Overflow for questions about extracting `t/F/p-values` from output.  From a statistical point of view, it's not clear why you would bother, since the results are statistically identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `names(ttest)` and `names(anova)`, and you'll see how to get t, F and p-values (even better is to check out `str` instead of `names`).

```
> t.test(x~grp1,dat)$statistic
        t 
0.9090048 
> t.test(x~grp1,dat)$p.value
[1] 0.383169
```

For the ANOVA, I suggest you use the `anova` function instead:

```
> anova(lm(x~grp2,dat))[1,"F value"]
[1] 0.2619048
> anova(lm(x~grp2,dat))[1,"Pr(>F)"]
[1] 0.6139134
```

**update:** if you just call like this you get an error

```
aaa(dset=dat,var=x,group=grp1)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = var ~ group, data = dset) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'group')
```

because your variable `x` has 24 numbers, but `grp1` has only 3 (`A B C`). It is not using your dataframe column names, but your variables. One thing you can do is pass the columns directly to the function:

```
aaa<-function(var,group) {
  if (length(levels(group))==2) {    
    print("ttest")
  }else{
    print("anova")
  }
}
aaa(dat$x, dat$grp1)
[1] "ttest"
aaa(dat$x, dat$grp2)
[1] "anova"
```

You can also [pass column names appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642201/1096117).