# R, pass column name as argument to function using dplyr::filter() and %in%

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

How can I pass a column name in a function similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function) but using `dplyr` chaining and `filter()` together with `%in%`.

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(8)
df <- data.frame(
  A=sample(c(1:3), 10, replace=T), 
  B=sample(c(1:3), 10, replace=T))
```

If want to get rows where column A is 1 or 2 I can do:

```
df %>% filter(A %in% c(1,2))
```

I get:

```
  A B
1 2 3
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 2 1
5 1 1
6 1 3
```

Now, how can I put this in a function, where one can specify the column, this does not work:

```
fun1 <- function(x, column, n){
  res <- 
    x %>% filter(column %in% n)
  return(res)
}
fun1(df, A, c(1,2))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try

```
fun1 <- function(x, column, n){
 x %>% 
  filter_(lazyeval::interp(quote(x %in% y), x=as.name(column), y=n))
 }
fun1(df, 'A', 1:2)
```

Or

```
fun2 <- function(x, column, n){
   args <- as.list(match.call())
   x %>%
     filter(eval(args$column, x) %in% n)
 }

 fun2(df, A, 1:2)
```

Comment: This is something good to see now. When I asked a similar question a while ago, @aosmith provided a nice answer. Here, I see an updated version. Today I am taking notes. :) +1

Comment: @akrun could you put an explanation for your option 2 - will `match.call()` contain all arguments that is put inside the function ? And how does this become interpretable by `filter()` in `eval()` ?

Comment: @user3375672  Yes, match.call() contains all the arguments.  Here, the dataset is the `envir` (i.e. `x`) for the column.  Please check `?eval`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your function, try:

```
fun1 <- function(x, column, n){
  res <- x %>% filter_(paste(column,"%in%",n))
  return(res)
}

fun1(df, "A", "c(1,2)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your function to

```
fun1 <- function(x, column, n){
    require(lazyeval)
    filter_(x,
        interp(quote(col %in% n),
            col = lazy(column), n = n))
}

all(fun1(df, A, c(1, 2)) == filter(df, A %in% c(1,2)))
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but stumbled across it in my search for this answer. I found something that is more simple and seems more intuitive to me. All that is required is adding double curly braces around the variable i.e. {{var}}.

```
fun1 <- function(x, column, n){
  res <- 
    x %>% filter({{column}} %in% n)
  return(res)
}
fun1(df, A, c(1,2))
```

Credit: https://www.schmidtynotes.com/blog/r/2021-12-20-pass-column-name-to-dplyr-function-in-function/