# In R: dcast in function, pass column names (again!)

Tags: r, function, casting, arguments, reshape2

Given a df in semi-long format with id variables `a` and `b` and measured data in columns `m1`and `m2`. The type of data is specified by the variable `v` (values var1 and var2).

```
set.seed(8)

df_l <- 
  data.frame(
    a = rep(sample(LETTERS,5),2),
    b = rep(sample(letters,5),2),
    v = c(rep("var1",5),rep("var2",5)),
    m1 = sample(1:10,10,F),
    m2 = sample(20:40,10,F))
```

Looks as:

```
   a b    v m1 m2
1  W r var1  3 40
2  N l var1  6 32
3  R a var1  9 28
4  F g var1  5 21
5  E u var1  4 38
6  W r var2  1 35
7  N l var2  8 33
8  R a var2 10 29
9  F g var2  7 30
10 E u var2  2 23
```

If I want to make a wide format of values in `m1` using id `a` as rows and values in `v1`as columns I do:

```
> reshape2::dcast(df_l, a~v, value.var="m1")
  a var1 var2
1 E    4    2
2 F    5    7
3 N    6    8
4 R    9   10
5 W    3    1
```

How do I write a function that does this were arguments to `dcast` (row, column and value.var) are supplied as arguments, something like:

```
fun <- function(df,row,col,val){
  require(reshape2)
  res <-
    dcast(df, row~col, value.var=val)
  return(res)
}
```

I checked SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324212/r-pass-column-name-as-argument-to-function-using-dplyrfilter-and-in?lq=1) to try variations of `match.call` and `eval(substitute())` in order to "get" the arguments inside the function, and also tried with the lazyeval package. No succes.

What am I doing wrong here ? How to get dcast to recognize variable names?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Formula argument also accepts character input.

```
foo <- function(df, id, measure, val) {
    dcast(df, paste(paste(id, collapse = " + "), "~", 
                    paste(measure, collapse = " + ")), 
          value.var = val)
}

require(reshape2)
foo(df_l, "a", "v", "m1")
```

---

Note that `data.table`'s `dcast` ([current development](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)) can also cast multiple `value.var` columns directly. So, you can also do:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5
foo(setDT(df_l), "a", "v", c("m1", "m2"))
#    a m1_var1 m1_var2 m2_var1 m2_var2
# 1: F       1       6      28      21
# 2: H       9       2      38      29
# 3: M       5      10      24      35
# 4: O       8       3      23      26
# 5: T       4       7      31      39
```

Comment: Two very good answers - I will chew further on the setDT function, seems awfully useful.

Comment: On the side: why does my line not work: dcast(df, row~col, value.var=val) ?

Comment: The error message from `reshape2::dcast` is quite cryptic. It's because `row ~ col` results in `dcast` looking for columns named `row` and `col` in your `df`. Install devel version of dt, load it and run `dcast(setDT(df), row ~ col, value.var="m1")`, and the error message should be quite clear.

Comment: multiple variable option is really useful!