# ggplot: percentile lines by group automation

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I've found the `dplyr` `%>%` operator helpful with simple ggplot2 transformations (without resorting to `ggproto`, which is required for [ggplot2 extensions](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html)), e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

gg.histo.pct.by.group <- function(g, ...) {
  g + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=unlist(lapply(unique(..group..), function(grp) ..count..[..group..==grp] / sum(..count..[..group..==grp])))), ...) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
    ylab("% of total count by group")
}

data = diamonds %>% select(carat, color) %>% filter(color %in% c('H', 'D'))

g = ggplot(data, aes(carat, fill=color)) %>% 
  gg.histo.pct.by.group(binwidth=0.5, position="dodge")
```

It's common to add some percentile lines with labels to these types of graphs, e.g.,

[image: R plot]

One cut'n'paste way of doing this is

```r
facts = data %>% 
  group_by(color) %>% 
  summarize(
    p50=quantile(carat, 0.5, na.rm=T), 
    p90=quantile(carat, 0.9, na.rm=T)
  )

ymax = ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range[2]

g +
  geom_vline(data=facts, aes(xintercept=p50, color=color), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  geom_vline(data=facts, aes(xintercept=p90, color=color), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  geom_text(data=facts, aes(x=p50, label=paste("p50=", p50), y=ymax, color=color), vjust=1.5, hjust=1, size=4, angle=90) +
  geom_text(data=facts, aes(x=p90, label=paste("p90=", p90), y=ymax, color=color), vjust=1.5, hjust=1, size=4, angle=90)
```

I'd love to encapsulate this into something like `g %>% gg.percentile.x(c(.5, .9))` but I haven't been able to find a good way to combine the use of `aes_` or `aes_string` with the discovery of the grouping columns in the graph object in order to calculate the percentiles correctly. I'd appreciate some help with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the most efficient way to create the desired plot consists from three steps:

1. Write two separate simple stats (following section **Creating a new stat** from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html): one for adding vertical lines at percentile locations and another for adding text labels;
2. Combine just written stats into the desired one with parameters as needed;
3. Use the results of work.

So the answer also consists from 3 parts.

**Part 1**. The stat for adding vertical lines at percentile locations should compute those values based on the data in x-axis and return the result in appropriate format. Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)

StatPercentileX <- ggproto("StatPercentileX", Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, probs) {
    percentiles <- quantile(data$x, probs=probs)
    data.frame(xintercept=percentiles)
    },
  required_aes = c("x")
)

stat_percentile_x <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "vline",
                              position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                              show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatPercentileX, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

The same goes for the stat for adding text labels (the default location is at the top of the plot):

```
StatPercentileXLabels <- ggproto("StatPercentileXLabels", Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales, probs) {
    percentiles <- quantile(data$x, probs=probs)
    data.frame(x=percentiles, y=Inf,
               label=paste0("p", probs*100, ": ",
                            round(percentiles, digits=3)))
    },
  required_aes = c("x")
)

stat_percentile_xlab <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "text",
                                     position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE,
                                     show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatPercentileXLabels, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

Already we have pretty powerful instruments that can be used in any fashion `ggplot2` can provide (colouring, grouping, faceting and so on). For example:

```
set.seed(1401)
plot_points <- data.frame(x_val=runif(100), y_val=runif(100),
                          g=sample(1:2, 100, replace=TRUE))
ggplot(plot_points, aes(x=x_val, y=y_val)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_percentile_x(probs=c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), linetype=2) +
  stat_percentile_xlab(probs=c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75), hjust=1, vjust=1.5, angle=90) +
  facet_wrap(~g)
# ggsave("Example_stat_percentile.png", width=10, height=5, units="in")
```

[image]

**Part 2** Although keeping separate layers for lines and text labels seems pretty natural (despite a little computational inefficiency of computing percentiles twice) adding two layers every time is quite verbose. Especially for this `ggplot2` has simple way of combining layers: put them in the list which is the result function call. The code is as follows:

```
stat_percentile_x_wlabels <- function(probs=c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) {
  list(
    stat_percentile_x(probs=probs, linetype=2),
    stat_percentile_xlab(probs=probs, hjust=1, vjust=1.5, angle=90)
  )
}
```

With this function previous example can be reproduced via the following command:

```
ggplot(plot_points, aes(x=x_val, y=y_val)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_percentile_x_wlabels() +
  facet_wrap(~g)
```

Note that `stat_percentile_x_wlabels` takes probabilities of the desired percentiles which are then passed to `quantile` function. This is the place to specify them.

**Part 3** Using again the idea of combining layers the plot in your question can be reproduced as follows:

```
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

geom_histo_pct_by_group <- function() {
  list(geom_histogram(aes(y=unlist(lapply(unique(..group..),
                                          function(grp) {
                                            ..count..[..group..==grp] /
                                              sum(..count..[..group..==grp])
                                            }))),
                      binwidth=0.5, position="dodge"),
         scale_y_continuous(labels = percent),
         ylab("% of total count by group")
       )
}

data = diamonds %>% select(carat, color) %>% filter(color %in% c('H', 'D'))

ggplot(data, aes(carat, fill=color, colour=color)) +
  geom_histo_pct_by_group() +
  stat_percentile_x_wlabels(probs=c(0.5, 0.9))
# ggsave("Question_plot.png", width=10, height=6, unit="in")
```

[image]

**Remarks**

1. The way this problem is solved here allows constructing more complex plots with percentile lines and labels;
2. With changing `x` to `y` (and vice versa), `vline` to `hline`, `xintercept` to `yintercept` in appropriate places one can define the same stats for the data from y-axis;
3. Of course if you like using `%>%` instead of `ggplot2`'s `+` you can wrap defined stats in functions just like you did in question post. Personally I wouldn't recommend that because it goes against standard use of `ggplot2`.

Comment: Excellent answer. I was unaware of the `list()` capability.

Answer (score 1):

I put your example into a function. You can dissect the non-standard evaluation in the `fact` data.frame. (Note: I don't like naming a data.frame `data` so I changed it to `mydata` in the example).

```
mydata = diamonds %>% select(carat, color) %>% filter(color %in% c('H', 'D'))

myFun <- function(df, X, col, bw, ...) {

  facts <- df %>% 
    group_by_(col) %>% 
    summarize_(
      p50= lazyeval::interp(~ quantile(var, 0.5, na.rm=TRUE), var = as.name(X)),
      p90= lazyeval::interp(~ quantile(var, 0.9, na.rm=TRUE), var = as.name(X))
    )

  gp <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = X, fill = col)) + 
          geom_histogram( position="dodge", binwidth = bw, aes(y=unlist(lapply(unique(..group..), function(grp) ..count..[..group..==grp] / sum(..count..[..group..==grp])))), ...) +
          scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + ylab("% of total count by group")

#  ymax = ggplot_build(g)$panel$ranges[[1]]$y.range[2] #doesnt work
  ymax = max(ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]$ymax)

  gp + aes_string(color = col) +
    geom_vline(data=facts, aes_string(xintercept="p50", color = col), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
    geom_vline(data=facts, aes_string(xintercept="p90", color = col), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
    geom_text(data=facts, aes(x=p50, label=paste("p50=", p50), y=ymax), vjust=1.5, hjust=1, size=4, angle=90) +
    geom_text(data=facts, aes(x=p90, label=paste("p90=", p90), y=ymax), vjust=1.5, hjust=1, size=4, angle=90)
}

myFun(df = mydata, X = "carat", col = "color", bw = 0.5)
```

[image: geom_histogram with NSE]

Another tip if you don't want to put quotes around your variables in your function calls is to set up your variables at the beginning of the function, via this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642201/4718512).

```
myOtherFun <- function(data, var1, var2, ...) { 
  #Value instead of string
  internal.var1 <- eval(substitute(var1), data, parent.frame()) 
  internal.var2 <- eval(substitute(var2), data, parent.frame())
  ggplot(data, aes(x = internal.var1, y = internal.var2)) + geom_point()
}

myOtherFun(mtcars, mpg, hp)   #note: mpg and hp aren't in quotes
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point()  #same result
```