# Pass df column names to nested equation in Graph Printing Function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, plot

I need some clarification on the primary post on [Passing a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function)

I need to create a function that will take a testSet, trainSet, and colName(aka predictor) as inputs to a function that prints a plot of the dataset with a GAM model trend line.

The issue I run into is:

```
 plot.model = function(predictor, train, test) {
      mod = gam(Response ~ s(train[[predictor]], spar = 1), data = train)
      ...
 }

 #Function Call
 plot.model("Predictor1", 1.0, crime.train, crime.test)
```

I can't simply pass the predictor as a string into the gam function, but I also can't use a string to index the data frame values as shown in the link above. Somehow, I need to pass the colName key to the game function. This issue occurs in other similar scenarios regarding plotting.

```
 plot <- ggplot(data = test, mapping = aes(x=predictor, y=ViolentCrimesPerPop))
```

Again, I can't pass a string value for the column name and I can't pass the column values either.

Does anyone have a generic solution for these situations. I apologize if the answer is buried in the above link, but it's not clear to me if it is.

Note: A working gam function call looks like this:

```
mod = gam(Response ~ s(Predictor1, spar = 1.0), data = train)
```

Where the train set is a data frame with column names "Response" & "Predictor".

Comment: Your current subset by column name should be working AFAIK.

Comment: Are you referring to passing train[[predictor]] to the gam function?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am referring to.

Comment: It does not. For example, mod = gam(train$Response ~ s(train$Predictor), ... does not work. It throws an error regarding nrows(train) != nrows(test) when trying to use the model to make predictions.

Comment: Is Predictor scalar or vector of column names?

Comment: "predictor" is a variable that needs to hold the name for an individual column name. "Predictor1" is an example of a working individual column name with values test$Predictor1. (edited question for clarify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aes_string` instead of `aes` when you pass a column name as string.

```
plot <- ggplot(data = test, mapping = aes_string(x=predictor, y=ViolentCrimesPerPop))
```

For `gam` function:: Example which is copied from `gam` function's documentation. I have used vector, scalar is even easier. Its just using `paste` with a `collapse` parameter.

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)

# String manipulate for formula
formula <- as.formula(paste("y~s(", paste(colnames(dat)[2:5], collapse = ")+s("), ")", sep =""))
b <- gam(formula, data=dat)
```

is same as

```
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
```

Comment: Awesome. How do I solve the indexing issue with GAM?