# function not accepting column call

Tags: r, dplyr

I have built a function where I want to pass a data frame and a column from the data frame. For example:

```
testdf <- structure(list(date = c("2016-04-04", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-04", 
"2016-04-04", "2016-04-04", "2016-04-04"), sensorheight = c(1L, 
16L, 1L, 16L, 1L, 16L), farm = c("McDonald", "McDonald", "McDonald", 
"McDonald", "McDonald", "McDonald"), location = c("4", "4", "5", 
"5", "Outside", "Outside"), Temp = c(122.8875, 117.225, 102.0375, 
98.3625, 88.5125, 94.7)), .Names = c("date", "sensorheight", 
"farm", "location", "Temp"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

> testdf
        date sensorheight     farm location     Temp
1 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        4 122.8875
2 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        4 117.2250
3 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        5 102.0375
4 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        5  98.3625
5 2016-04-04            1 McDonald  Outside  88.5125
6 2016-04-04           16 McDonald  Outside  94.7000
```

The function subtracts some values from others based the values in different columns. It was working, accepting the data frame and column inputs, but since updating R, its not working.

```
DailyInOutDiff <- function (df, variable) {

  DailyInOutDiff04 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(4, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else variable[location=="4"] - variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "4")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  DailyInOutDiff05 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(5, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else variable[location=="5"] - variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "5")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  temp.list <- list(DailyInOutDiff04, DailyInOutDiff05)
  final.df = bind_rows(temp.list)
  return(final.df)
}

test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, "Temp")
test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, quote(Temp))
```

They produce the following error messages:

```
  Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

And

```
  Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable.
```

I would like to know the meaning of these error messages and how to address them.

I tried these solutions [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function), however none of the solutions worked for me.

The errors do not occur if I remove the column as an input, but I need the column because I am applying the function to multiple columns in a large data frame.

The output I would like:

```
        date sensorheight     farm location     Temp
1 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        4  34.3750
2 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        4  22.5250
3 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        5  13.5250
4 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        5   3.6625
```

Comment: Suggested dupe: [use dynamic column names in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26003574/903061)

Comment: Also see the package vignette [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html)

Comment: Could you provide the output you're hoping to get?

Comment: @beigel see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest `dplyr` (0.7) you can use `.data` to refer to the column name with a string, Your function would be modified as such:

```
DailyInOutDiff <- function (df, variable) {

  DailyInOutDiff04 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(4, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else .data[[variable]][location=="4"] - .data[[variable]][location=='Outside'], 
              location = "4")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  DailyInOutDiff05 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(5, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else .data[[variable]][location=="5"] - .data[[variable]][location=='Outside'], 
              location = "5")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  temp.list <- list(DailyInOutDiff04, DailyInOutDiff05)
  final.df = bind_rows(temp.list)
  return(final.df)
}
```

The change from `variable[...]` to `.data[[variable]][...]` means it now selects the column specified by the string in `variable`, instead of trying to index the actual string. Running this function with the provided data returns:

```
DailyInOutDiff(testdf, "Temp")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   date, sensorheight [2]
#>         date sensorheight     farm location    Diff
#>        <chr>        <int>    <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        4 34.3750
#> 2 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        4 22.5250
#> 3 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        5 13.5250
#> 4 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        5  3.6625
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't replicate the second error, but I could replicate the first one. It seems that the `summarise` function has trouble calling `Temp`, because it considers it to be a `character` object. In other words, you are calling a column name, and not a column. If you run the code inside the function line-by-line, and instead of `variable` you use `df$variable` you will see that it works.

That being said, the solution is pretty simple. I just added the line `variable<- as.name(variable)` in your function. Now it reads:

```
DailyInOutDiff <- function (df, variable) {

  variable<- as.name(variable)
  DailyInOutDiff04 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(4, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else variable[location=="4"] - variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "4")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  DailyInOutDiff05 <- df %>%
    filter(location %in% c(5, 'Outside')) %>% 
    group_by(date, sensorheight, farm) %>%
    arrange(sensorheight, farm, location) %>%
    summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else variable[location=="5"] - variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "5")  %>%
    select(1, 2, 3, 5, 4)

  temp.list <- list(DailyInOutDiff04, DailyInOutDiff05)
  final.df = bind_rows(temp.list)
  return(final.df)
}
```

And the output is:

```
> test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, "Temp")
> test
Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
Groups: date, sensorheight [2]

        date sensorheight     farm location    Diff
       <chr>        <int>    <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
1 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        4 34.3750
2 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        4 22.5250
3 2016-04-04            1 McDonald        5 13.5250
4 2016-04-04           16 McDonald        5  3.6625
```

Answer (score 0):

The following calls the function DailyInOutDiff and assigns **testdf** to **df** and **"Temp"** to **variable**.

```
   test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, "Temp")
   test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, quote(Temp))
```

As per what you are trying to do , you want to pass a data frame and a column from the data frame. At present you are passing only the **column name** which is a string and not the **column**. You must change it to

```
      test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, testdf["Temp"])
```

Secondly, you are passing **Temp** column and trying to filter the  variable dataframe based on **location** in the following piece of code.

summarise(Diff = if(n()==1) NA else variable[location=="4"] - variable[location=='Outside'], 
              location = "4")

It must be,

```
    variable[variable$location=="4",]
```

if your call is,

```
    test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, testdf["Temp"])
```

or

```
   variable[variable$Temp=="4",]
```

if you call is,

```
    test <- DailyInOutDiff(testdf, testdf["Temp"])
```