# Use R function to replaces strings as factor in the same dataframe

Tags: r, character-encoding

I would like to transform certain columns with a specific string code to a factor in the same data.frame. However, I am stymied by the initial task of passing the data.frame column reference to my function. Working from examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function) and its linked pages, I believe the following should work:

```
#feed string to function

set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
chr1 = sample(letters[1:4], 10, T),
chr2 = sample(letters[4:7], 10, T), 
stringsAsFactors = F
)

tofactor <- function(dat,column) {
  dat[,column] <- as.factor(dat[,column])
}

tofactor(df, "chr1")
typeof(df$chr1)
```

However, the result of this operation is persistence of string encoding for `df$chr1`. I have also tried a reference using a double square brackets approach without success.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: add `dat` as the final line in your function

Comment: Previous poster is incorrect; your function is fine. Your problem is that you don't assign the result of the `tofactor` function to anything. Use `df$chr1 <- tofactor(df, "chr1")`. Also, use `=` and not `<-` inside your call to `data.frame()`.

Comment: previous poster's advice is silly; my way is better

Comment: Why doesn't the single line of the function accomplish the intended replacement?

Comment: it _does_ do the replacement, but your function is returning the value that is returned by `\`[<-\`` which, in this case, is just the result of `as.factor(dat[,column])`. to get the object that contains the replacement, you need to return `dat` instead. if your goal was simply to get the vector back, then I would tend to agree more with previous poster and call myself incorrect

Comment: @Todd You should spend some time to study scoping in R. Changes inside a function (usually, with few special exceptions that you normally should avoid) don't affect objects outside a function. You should return the changed data.frame and assign it to the original data.frame.

Comment: My plan was to place the column names in a vector and then `apply()` for each value in the vector. Based on these comments, it would seem this strategy may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use `mutate_at` and specify the variables inside of `var`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  chr1 = sample(letters[1:4], 10, T),
  chr2 = sample(letters[4:7], 10, T), 
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df2 <- df %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(chr1), as.factor)

class(df2$chr1) #[1] "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is working fine, all you need to do is assign the output to the original (or a new df).

`df <- tofactor(df, "chr1")`

If you run `str(tofactor(df,"chr1"))` you get the return:

`Factor w/ 4 levels "a","b","c","d": 4 4 2 4 3 3 3 1 3 3`

Answer (score 0):

After understanding scope better and direction to `assign()` from a colleague, I've arrived at:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  chr1 = sample(letters[1:4], 10, T),
  chr2 = sample(letters[4:7], 10, T), 
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

tofactor <- function(dat,column) {
  dat[,column] <- as.factor(dat[,column])
  assign("df",dat, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

tofactor(df, "chr1")
typeof(df$chr1)
```

This solution handles the replacement in the function, which allows for repeated use without having to assign the output in an additional step.