# Loop through vector of variables

Tags: r, loops

I have a process that I'd like to loop through one variable at a time.

Although my process is much more complicated, I've used the below to illustrate the basic problem.

Suppose I want to build a histogram and do lots of other stuff for each variable in `iris`.  The following accomplishes that goal:

```
hist(iris$Sepal.Length, main = paste("Histogram of Sepal.Length"))
hist(iris$Sepal.Width, main = paste("Histogram of Sepal.Width"))
hist(iris$Petal.Length, main = paste("Histogram of Petal.Length"))
hist(iris$Petal.Width, main = paste("Histogram of Petal.Width"))
```

However, my data frame is much larger, and my process much more complex.  I'd like to wrap this in a loop like below (this does not work, but is how I'm envisioning in my head).

```
name.list <- names(iris)

for (i in 1:4) {

  print(i)
  print(name.list[i])
  print(paste0('iris$', name.list[i]))

  hist(paste0('iris$', name.list[i]), main = paste("Histogram of ", name.list[i]))

  # A bunch of other stuff I need to do with this variable
  # ...
  # ...

}
```

What am I missing here?  How can I wrap this code to loop through one at a time?

Comment: Double square brackets gets the column by value of the thing in the brackets. So  `iris[[ name.list[i] ]]` .

Comment: Thanks.  This would definitely get me where I'm going, but the answer Joris provided looks like a cleaner and better way to do this.

Comment: @pyll my answer is actually the exact same as Spacedman gave you. I just wrote it out a bit more so it's easier to read for R novices. The key message here is the use of `[[`. Spacedman was very right about that.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  He gave me exactly what I was looking for, but the piece you added that I think makes it cleaner is not creating the `name.list` vector at all.  Either way, thank you both for helping me get this sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier if you treat a data.frame as a list. An object of class `data.frame` is a list, so you can use the list selection `[[` here:

```
for( i in names(iris)){
  tmp <- iris[[i]]
  if(is.numeric(tmp))
    hist(tmp, main = paste("Histogram of",i))
}
```

See also the answers to this question : [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function)