# Calling passed column name in a function

Tags: r, tidyverse

Code that works:

```
scale_this <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)
}

get_the_boxes <- function(df,y,val1,provider_id){

  temp <- df %>%
    group_by_("MPIN") %>%
    # mutate(y = scale_this(y),PAID_DATE_GRP = scale_this(PAID_DATE_GRP))
    mutate(y = scale_this(mbr_cnt_log))

  return(temp)
}
```

edit:
Want to add how I call the function:

```
my_data  <- get_the_boxes(new2,"mbr_cnt_log",1,"mpin")
```

However, I want to pass the column name "mbr_cnt_log" via parameter "y". I've seen answers to similar questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function) was a good example), but  they have failed for me (user error, no doubt).

Only showing the line with a change, here's what I've tried and the error returned:

change:

```
mutate(y = scale_this(deparse(substitute(y))))
```

error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

change:

```
mutate(y = scale_this(df[[y]]))
```

error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `y` must be length 24 (the group size) or one, not 0
```

change:

```
mutate(y = scale_this(df[,y]))
```

error:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Column `"mbr_cnt_log"` not found.
```

Comment: You'll probably need to do something like `!!rlang::sym(y)`. There's a whole new system for doing this stuff in dplyr that you're going to have to google, read about and learn.

Comment: you can try to go around if nothing else come up, 
temp$y <- temp[,y] #where y is name of column
#scaling 
temp[,y] <- temp$y #rewrite the initial column

Answer (score 2):

With the lastest version of `dplyr`, you use `enquo` and the bang-bang `!!` operator to capture and expand symbols into dplyr expressions

```
get_the_boxes <- function(df, y) {
  y <- enquo(y)
  df %>%
    group_by(hp) %>%
    mutate(!!quo_name(y) := scale_this(!!y))
}

get_the_boxes(mtcars, disp)
```

Comment: This gives me this error:  " Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator."

Comment: @DerylGarland Maybe check your dplyr version. I tested with `dplyr_0.7.4`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got t work:

```
get_the_boxes <- function(df,y,val1,provider_id){
  y<-enquo(y)

  temp <- df %>%
    group_by_("MPIN") %>%
    # mutate(y = scale_this(y),PAID_DATE_GRP = scale_this(PAID_DATE_GRP))
    mutate(y = scale_this(!!y))

  return(temp)
}

my_data <- get_the_boxes(new2,mbr_cnt_log,1,"mpin")
```

This is essentially what MrFlick wrote, but a bit different. I found [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/programming-with-dplyr-by-using-dplyr/) to help.