# issues using survminer::ggsurvplot to plot many survival curves programmatically in r

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I can plot a single Kaplan-Meier plot like below with ggsurvplot:

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
fit1 = survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = lung)
```

However, I need to plot many KM plot programmatically. I need to pass different variables as strings. I tried below.

```
fml = as.formula(paste('Surv(time, status)~', 'sex'))
fit2 = survfit(fml, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit2, data = lung)
```

surprisingly, this does not work. I got the error message below:

```
Error: object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

I don't know why this happens. Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/252

Comment: `fit2 <- do.call(survfit, args = list(formula = fml, data = lung))`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested at the link in [Aidan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54190948/issues-using-survminerggsurvplot-to-plot-many-survival-curves-programmatically#comment95209877_54190948), you need to use the function `survminer::surv_fit()`, which is a wrapper around `survival::survfit()`. So, in your example,

```
library(survminer)
library(survival)
 # lung is distributed as an object, survival::lung
fit1 = surv_fit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit1, data = lung)
```

The output from `surv_fit(object.formula)` can then be plotted

```
fml = as.formula(paste('Surv(time, status)~', 'sex'))
fit2 = surv_fit(fml, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit2, data = lung)
```

In the `surv_fit` help page it also shows how to fit a list of formulae.

Comment: A clearly underestimated answer!