# Function parameter; passing variable name without quotes

Tags: r, dplyr

The question is similar than this one:

[Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653)

I have a function:

```
optimal_cutpoint <- function(data, ..., choice){
  selection <- dplyr::select(data, ...)
  choice <- data[[choice]]
  # do something with those two objects
}
```

The function I would use the following way:

```
choicedata <- data.frame(PTV.A = c(0, 10, 5, 4, 7, 1, 2, 0, 0, 10),
                     PTV.B = c(5, 0, 1, 10, 6, 7, 10, 9, 5, 0),
                     PTV.C = c(10, 5, 10, 5, 2, 8, 0, 5, 5, 0),
                     VOTE = c("C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "C", "B","B", "B", "A"))
optimal_cutpoint(choicedata, PTV.A:PTV.C, choice = "VOTE")
```

Now to my question. With the ... I can write the variable names without quotes. Is there a possibility that I can write the "VOTE" without the quotes? I would prefere to write it without quotes to be consistent in the function.

If I use dplyr::select it searches for choice instead of vote.

```
dplyr::select(data,choice)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the line marked ##

```
optimal_cutpoint <- function(data, ..., choice){
  selection <- dplyr::select(data, ...)
  choice <- deparse(substitute(choice)) ##
  choice <- data[[choice]]
  # do something with those two objects
}

out <- optimal_cutpoint(choicedata, PTV.A:PTV.C, choice = VOTE)
out
## [1] C A C B B C B B B A
## Levels: A B C
```

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what quosures are for, see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-expressions) for more info. Bonus reference to `pull` which is basically the dplyr equivalent to `[[`.

```
optimal_cutpoint <- function(data, ..., choice){
  choice_quo = enquo(choice)
  selection <- dplyr::select(data, ...)
  choice <-dplyr::pull(data, !!choice_quo)
  # do something with those two objects
}
```

I'm surprised that things work automagically with unquoted arguments in `...`, I never tried that before.

**EDIT** some extra clarification on `quo` and `enquo`, since I made this mistake in my original answer. Use `quo` if you are using an unquoted value directly, and `enquo` if you are interpreting the *value of an unquoted argument* to a function. Compare

```
data(iris)
myvar = quo(Species)
select(iris, !!myvar)
```

to

```
myfun = function(d, myvar) {
  quovar = enquo(myvar)
  select(iris, !!quovar)
}
myfun(iris, Species)
```