# applicate function on dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I need to create a function that returns the vector of unique values of a column of a dataframe. As input, i should mention the data frame and the column name.
this is what i did :

```
Val_Uniques <- function(df, col) {
 return(unique(df$col))
}

Val_Uniques(mytable, city)
```

the result is NULL, how can i fix it please ? 
I want to add a trycatchblock and print awarning message "the column does not exist" if the name of the column is wrong.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're looking for `deparse(substitute(x))` and `get()` here. The former converts the specified names into strings, the latter loads your data at the first place. For the exception we simply could use an `if` expression.

```
Val_Uniques <- function(df, col) {
  df <- deparse(substitute(df))
  df <- get(df)
  col <- deparse(substitute(col))
  if(!(col %in% names(df)))
    stop("the column does not exist")
  return(unique(df[[col]]))
}
```

***Test***

```
> Val_Uniques(mytable, city)
[1] A D B C E
Levels: A B C D E

> Val_Uniques(mytable, foo)
Error in Val_Uniques(mytable, foo) : the column does not exist
```

***Data***

```
mytable <- data.frame(city=LETTERS[c(1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 4)],
                      var=c(1, 3, 22, 4, 5, 8, 7, 9))
```

Comment: What's an alternative to `deparse(substitute)`. I always use this but feel it's repetitive. I've seen usage of `enquo` but it often looks more work than the former. What's an "easy" alternative?

Comment: Well, I would say it is a common practice to do it this way, and everyone will immediately see what your function does.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A", "B", "C", "C"),
                 val = c(1,2,3,3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Val_Uniques <- function(df, col) {
  return(unique(df[, col]))
}

Val_Uniques(df, "id")

[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

This link helps with passing column names to functions: [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function)

Comment: It works ! Thank you Hakki :) 
Do you have any idea about exception handling here ?

Comment: I think you should make reproducible example, but before that search tryCatch, possibly, safely and basic ifelse.