# Pass an Object Through a Function

Tags: r, function

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function) question discusses the issue, but I need to pass the object through my function. For example:

```
foo <- function(data, col1, col2) {
  boxplot(
    formula = col1 ~ col2,
    data = data)
}
```

When I run this:

```
foo(data, col1, col2)
```

I get `object 'col1' not found`.

How do I pass `col1` and `col2` through?

Comment: a formula is an object as well, why can't you do `foo <- function(data, formula = col1 ~ col2) boxplot(formula, data)` as a trivial function? If you must pass variable names, use `reformulate` instead of reconstructing a formula with `as.formula(paste(deparse(substutute(...`

Comment: @rawr Could you give an example of how to use reformulate?

Comment: from your example, it looks like you would need `reformulate('col2', 'col1')` or if you had multiple variables on the right, `reformulate(c('col3', 'col2'), 'col1')` or vectors for one or both would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we could construct the formula from unquoted arguments by first converting to string with `deparse/substitute` and then use `paste` to create the formula

```
foo <- function(data, col1, col2) {
  col1 <- deparse(substitute(col1))
  col2 <- deparse(substitute(col2))
  boxplot(
     formula = as.formula(paste0(col1, "~", col2)),
        data = data)
  }
```

-test it with inbuilt dataset

```
foo(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

[image]

---

Or if we prefer to use `tidyverse`, use the curly-curly (`{{..}}`) operator for simultaneously convert to quosures (`enquo`) and evaluate  (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
foo2 <- function(data, col1, col2) {
     data %>%
       select({{col1}}, {{col2}}) %>% 
       mutate( {{col2}} := factor({{col2}})) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = {{col2}}, y = {{col1}})) + 
           geom_boxplot()
           }
       
foo2(mtcars, mpg, cyl)
```

[image]