# A R function to transform column values into new ones does not work

Tags: r

I have written a function to change values not being NA in each column into a new value. The following example illustrates the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,NA,1,1,NA),
             B=c(NA,1,NA,1,NA),
             C=c(1,NA,1,NA,1))
```

1's should be changed into 0's with the function:

```
cambio <- function(d,v){
  d[[v]][!is.na(d[[v]])] <- 0
}
```

The column is named within the function with [[]], and it is passed with quotes as argument to the function. I learned this in a clear and useful [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function?answertab=votes#tab-top) to the post [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function?answertab=votes#tab-top).
However, after running the function, for example, with the first variable,

```
cambio(df,"A")
```

the values of tha column keep unchanged.
Why this function does not work as expected?

Comment: The function operates on a local copy of the data.frame.  You should return the value then assign it back into the original if you want to alter the original df.  `cambio <- function(d,v){
  d[[v]][!is.na(d[[v]])] <- 0; return(d)}; df <- cambio(df,"A")`

Comment: Great! It works.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
d[[v]][!is.na(d[[v]])] <- 0
```

But this tells it to put a zero on any *not* `NA`, so you want:

```
cambio <- function(d,v){
  d[[v]][is.na(d[[v]])] <- 0
  return(d)
}
```

EDIT:: you're just missing the `return(d)` statement.

Comment: Oh! Thats what I get for skimming.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few base R solutions:

one:

```
replace(df, df == 1, 0)
```

two:

```
replace(df, !is.na(df), 0)
```

three:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, pmin, 0))
```