# Pass a data.table column name to a function using :=

Tags: r, data.table

This question is the data.table equivalent of [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653).

Suppose I have a very simple data.table:

```
dat <- data.table(x = 1:4,
                  y = 5:8)
```

Now I want to create a new column for any given function:

```
new_column <- function(df,col_name,expr){
    col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
    df[[col_name]] <- eval(substitute(expr),df,parent.frame())
    df
}
```

So that it correctly provides:

```
> new_column (dat,z,x+y)
  x y  z
1 1 5  6
2 2 6  8
3 3 7 10
4 4 8 12
```

However , because it is a data.table I would like to create this new column using `:=`:

```
new_column_byref <- function(df,col_name,expr){
   col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
  df[, col_name:=eval(substitute(expr)
                      ,df
                      ,parent.frame()
                      )]
  df
}
```

But it does not work:

```
> a <- new_column_byref(dat,z,x+y)
 Error: Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, :=, `:=`(...) and let(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set` is the data.table-idiomatic way. If you need to do other stuff like use `by`, `rlang` has a generic way to delay evaluation, which is to `enexpr` the args (or enquo if you want them evaluated in the original environment) and `!!` them inside an `inject` with the expression you'd normally use.

```r
library(rlang)
#> Warning: package 'rlang' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:rlang':
#> 
#>     :=

dat <- data.table(x = 1:4,
                  y = 5:8)

new_column <- function(df, col_name, expr) {
    col_name <- enexpr(col_name)
    expr <- enexpr(expr)
    inject(df[, !!col_name := !!expr])
}

new_column(dat, z, x + y)

dat
#>        x     y     z
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1:     1     5     6
#> 2:     2     6     8
#> 3:     3     7    10
#> 4:     4     8    12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or, similarly without rlang

```r
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(x = 1:4,
                  y = 5:8)

new_column <- function(df, col_name, expr) {
    col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
    expr <- substitute(expr)
    df[, (col_name) := eval(expr)]
}

new_column(dat, z, x + y)

dat
#>        x     y     z
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1:     1     5     6
#> 2:     2     6     8
#> 3:     3     7    10
#> 4:     4     8    12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Using the "programming on the language" interface in the dev version.

https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(x = 1:4,
                  y = 5:8)

new_column <- function(df, col_name, expr) {
    df[, col_name := expr, 
       env = list(col_name = substitute(col_name), 
                  expr = substitute(expr))]
}

new_column(dat, z, x + y)

dat
#>        x     y     z
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1:     1     5     6
#> 2:     2     6     8
#> 3:     3     7    10
#> 4:     4     8    12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or using `match.call`

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(x = 1:4,
                  y = 5:8)

new_column <- function(df, col_name, expr) {
    fun_call <- match.call()
    df[, col_name := expr, 
       env = as.list(fun_call)[c('col_name', 'expr')]]
}

new_column(dat, z, x + y)

dat
#>        x     y     z
#>    <int> <int> <int>
#> 1:     1     5     6
#> 2:     2     6     8
#> 3:     3     7    10
#> 4:     4     8    12
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thanks. this is great. i was worried about this very thing.. ie, my solution did not allow for `by`. thanks for the additional answer.

Comment: It allows expressions as well, you just need to quote them to prevent from early evaluation

Comment: Thanks @jangorecki, good to know. Added to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
new_column_byref <- function(df,col_name,expr){
  col_name <- deparse(substitute(col_name))
  set(df,j=col_name,value=eval(substitute(expr),df,parent.frame()))
}


dat <- data.table(x = 1:4,y = 5:8)

new_column_byref(dat,z,x+y)[]

   x y  z
1: 1 5  6
2: 2 6  8
3: 3 7 10
4: 4 8 12
```

Comment: Great, set () is the funcional form of ':=' , I missed that. Thank you.