# Creating parametrized function in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This question is realted to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273018/pass-a-data-table-column-name-to-a-function-using).

I need a parametrized function to implement the following code:

```
dt <- data.table(  text = c("AAA 123 BBB", "1 CCC")
                 , text2 = c("AAA 123 BBB", "1 CCC"))

double_number <- function(x) x*2
regex_identify_num <- "\\d+" 

dt[, calc_value := text |> str_extract(regex_identify_num) |> as.numeric ()|> double_number()]
dt[, text := mapply(function(x,y) gsub(regex_identify_num, x, y, perl = T), calc_value, text)]
dt[, calc_value:=NULL]
```

The expected result  is to get the numbers doubled in the selected column, as per the code above.
I tried:

```
change_value <- function(dt_, fun, regex, column_name) {
  #browser()
  dt_[, new_column := get(column_name) |> str_extract(get(regex)) |> fun()]
  dt_[, column_name := mapply(function(x, y) gsub(get(regex), x, y, perl = T), new_column, get(column_name))]
  dt_[, new_column := NULL]
  return(dt)
}

change_value(dt, function(x) x |> as.numeric ()|> double_number(), "regex_identify_num", "text")
```

But I get `Error in get(column_name) : first argument has length > 1`. Interestingly, when debugging the evaluation of `get(column_name) |> str_extract(get(regex)) |> fun()` seems correct (246 2).

How do I fix this?

PS> I also tried a different approach (programming through data.table),no success:

```
change_value <- function(dt_, fun, regex, column_name) {
  #browser()
  dt_[, new_column:= column_name|> str_extract(regex) |> fun()
      , env = list(  fun = substitute(fun)
                   , column_name = substitute(column_name)
                   , regex = substitute(regex)
                   )
      ]
  dt_[, column_name := mapply(function(x, y) gsub(regex, x, y, perl = T), new_column, column_name)]
  dt_[, new_column := NULL]
  return(dt)
}
```

Comment: See new 'env' argument in devel version of dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error does not occur on the first pass, only on the second pass (and subsequent),

```r
dt
#           text       text2
#         <char>      <char>
# 1: AAA 123 BBB AAA 123 BBB
# 2:       1 CCC       1 CCC
change_value(dt, function(x) x |>
  as.numeric ()|>
  double_number(), "regex_identify_num", "text")[]
#           text       text2 column_name
#         <char>      <char>      <char>
# 1: AAA 123 BBB AAA 123 BBB AAA 246 BBB
# 2:       1 CCC       1 CCC       2 CCC
dt
#           text       text2 column_name
#         <char>      <char>      <char>
# 1: AAA 123 BBB AAA 123 BBB AAA 246 BBB
# 2:       1 CCC       1 CCC       2 CCC
change_value(dt, function(x) x |>
  as.numeric ()|>
  double_number(), "regex_identify_num", "text")[]
# Error in get(column_name) : first argument has length > 1
```

Part of this is that, due to `data.table` referential semantics, your `dt` is modified *in-place*. Perhaps this is by design. But when you do so, the non-standard evaluation behaves a little differently: while you have `get(column_name)` inside of a `data.table` namespace, `column_name` both exists as a vector in the function *and* as a column in the frame, the third column above.

We can work around this by using `data.table`'s `..varname` semantics.

```r
change_value <- function(dt_, fun, regex, column_name) {
  #browser()
  dt_[, new_column := get(..column_name) |> str_extract(get(..regex)) |> fun()]
  dt_[, column_name := mapply(function(x, y) gsub(get(..regex), x, y, perl = T), new_column, get(..column_name))]
  dt_[, new_column := NULL]
  return(dt)
}
change_value(dt, function(x) x |>
  as.numeric ()|>
  double_number(), "regex_identify_num", "text")[]
#           text       text2 column_name
#         <char>      <char>      <char>
# 1: AAA 123 BBB AAA 123 BBB AAA 246 BBB
# 2:       1 CCC       1 CCC       2 CCC
change_value(dt, function(x) x |>
  as.numeric ()|>
  double_number(), "regex_identify_num", "text")[]
#           text       text2 column_name
#         <char>      <char>      <char>
# 1: AAA 123 BBB AAA 123 BBB AAA 246 BBB
# 2:       1 CCC       1 CCC       2 CCC
```

(repeated runs do not err).

Another option would be to name your argument and your new-column differently.

Factoid: the `..`-referencing works in the `j=` part of `data.table::[`, but not in `i=`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I would never get that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Building upon r2evans observation, the key point is to enclose column_name in parentesis when atributing the result back to it:

```
dt_[, (column_name) := mapply(function(x, y) gsub(get(regex), x, y, perl = T), new_column, get(column_name))]
```

By doing this we avoid name clashes, and can skip the `..` .

Then the full code becomes:

```
change_value <- function(dt_, fun, regex, column_name) {
  #browser()
  dt_[, new_column := get(column_name) |> str_extract(get(regex)) |> fun()]
  dt_[, (column_name) := mapply(function(x, y) gsub(get(regex), x, y, perl = T), new_column, get(column_name))]
  dt_[, new_column := NULL]
  return(dt)
}
```