# Create a function that for any 2 variables in any dataset will generate a crosstable in R lang

Tags: r

I tried the following code:

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(data$var1, data$var2)

ct <- function(a, b){
  CrossTable(data$a, data$b)
```

But it returns an error and I doubt it is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you want.
If you pass two vectors `a` and `b` it simply calls `CrossTable` but if you pass columns of a data.frame, it must subset the df by those columns names. A `deparse1/substitute` trick will get the colnames, then subset with `[[`, see [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function).

```r
ct <- function(a, b, data){
  if(missing(data)) {
    gmodels::CrossTable(a, b)
  } else {
    a <- deparse1(substitute(a))
    b <- deparse1(substitute(b))
    gmodels::CrossTable(data[[a]], data[[b]])
  }
}
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Call the function on two vectors.

```r
x <- sample(letters[1:4], 1000, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(2, 1000, replace = TRUE)
ct(x, y)
#> 
#>  
#>    Cell Contents
#> |-------------------------|
#> |                       N |
#> | Chi-square contribution |
#> |           N / Row Total |
#> |           N / Col Total |
#> |         N / Table Total |
#> |-------------------------|
#> 
#>  
#> Total Observations in Table:  1000 
#> 
#>  
#>              | b 
#>            a |         1 |         2 | Row Total | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            a |       122 |       118 |       240 | 
#>              |     0.042 |     0.042 |           | 
#>              |     0.508 |     0.492 |     0.240 | 
#>              |     0.244 |     0.236 |           | 
#>              |     0.122 |     0.118 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            b |       128 |       126 |       254 | 
#>              |     0.012 |     0.012 |           | 
#>              |     0.504 |     0.496 |     0.254 | 
#>              |     0.257 |     0.251 |           | 
#>              |     0.128 |     0.126 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            c |       122 |       125 |       247 | 
#>              |     0.013 |     0.013 |           | 
#>              |     0.494 |     0.506 |     0.247 | 
#>              |     0.244 |     0.250 |           | 
#>              |     0.122 |     0.125 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            d |       127 |       132 |       259 | 
#>              |     0.039 |     0.039 |           | 
#>              |     0.490 |     0.510 |     0.259 | 
#>              |     0.255 |     0.263 |           | 
#>              |     0.127 |     0.132 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#> Column Total |       499 |       501 |      1000 | 
#>              |     0.499 |     0.501 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#> 
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Call the function on a data frame's columns. The data set is the 3rd argument.

```r
ct(cyl, am, mtcars)
#> 
#>  
#>    Cell Contents
#> |-------------------------|
#> |                       N |
#> | Chi-square contribution |
#> |           N / Row Total |
#> |           N / Col Total |
#> |         N / Table Total |
#> |-------------------------|
#> 
#>  
#> Total Observations in Table:  32 
#> 
#>  
#>              | data[[b]] 
#>    data[[a]] |         0 |         1 | Row Total | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            4 |         3 |         8 |        11 | 
#>              |     1.909 |     2.790 |           | 
#>              |     0.273 |     0.727 |     0.344 | 
#>              |     0.158 |     0.615 |           | 
#>              |     0.094 |     0.250 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            6 |         4 |         3 |         7 | 
#>              |     0.006 |     0.009 |           | 
#>              |     0.571 |     0.429 |     0.219 | 
#>              |     0.211 |     0.231 |           | 
#>              |     0.125 |     0.094 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#>            8 |        12 |         2 |        14 | 
#>              |     1.636 |     2.391 |           | 
#>              |     0.857 |     0.143 |     0.438 | 
#>              |     0.632 |     0.154 |           | 
#>              |     0.375 |     0.062 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#> Column Total |        19 |        13 |        32 | 
#>              |     0.594 |     0.406 |           | 
#> -------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#> 
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>