# R: Use column name of df as input for custom function

Tags: r, dataframe, function, character

I am trying to make a custom function that takes a df and the name of the column I want to apply the function to. however I am having trouble calling my function.

When I enter the name of the column without parentheses, I get "Error: object 'Area' not found". When I enter the column name as a character, I get "Error in model.frame.default(form, data) :
variable lengths differ (found for 'Treatment')".

I am guessing I need to re-characterize my column name inside the function, but I don't know what to do.

```
AssumTests <- function(data, aspect){
  # Homogeneity of Variance test
  lt <- leveneTest(aspect ~ Treatment, 
             data = data)
  
  model  <- lm(aspect ~ Treatment, data = data)
  
  # Normality residuals as group
  qq <- ggqqplot(residuals(model))
  st <- shapiro_test(residuals(model))
  
  # Normality test by group
  qqfac <- ggqqplot(data, paste(aspect), facet.by = "Treatment")
  spfac <- data %>%
    group_by(Treatment) %>%
    shapiro_test(aspect)
  
  list = list(lt, qq, st, qqfac, spfac)
  return(list)
}
```

```
AssumTests(FluorByTreatment_Iter1.df, "Area")
```

Crossposted to: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/1b0zkx0/use_column_name_of_df_as_input_for_custom_function/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button)

UPDATE:
Got the first expressions to work with `data[[aspect]]`, but still having trouble with the last expression using dplyr piping. I tried the `{{aspect}}` trick, but R is still recognizing the quotes: "Column `"Area"` doesn't exist."

UPDATE2: Got the final expression to work, thanks to this[Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/1b0zkx0/comment/ksbib34/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) using `!!sym(column)`

Comment: please include the necessary packages in the code.

Comment: try wrapping it in double curly braces all throughout the function -  `{{aspect}}` - if that doesnt work please edit this question to be reproducible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a data.frame column name to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641653/pass-a-data-frame-column-name-to-a-function) - specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895032/12109788) since you're using `dplyr`

Comment: @jpsmith my column is just decimal numbers if that helps. I don't know exactly how to give a reproducible question

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? Did you read the question and answers in the links? None of that has to do with the type of data in the column. If you need help making it reproducible, read [how to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) - good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith Solved 3/4 expressions. Yes I have read the links, but still getting mixed up on the last one. The {{}} isn't working. This seems like it should be simple since its tidyverse.

Comment: For the formulas, if you’re passing `aspect` as a character, you can use `reformulate()` — eg, `lt <- leveneTest(reformulate("Treatment", response = aspect), data = data)`. For `shapiro_test()`, you might be able to use `.data[[aspect]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Got the first 3 expressions to work with data[[aspect]], and got the final expression to work, using !!sym(column)

So final code being:

```
AssumTests <- function(data, aspect){
  # Homogeneity of Variance test
  lt <- leveneTest(data[[aspect]] ~ Treatment, 
             data = data)
  
  model  <- lm(data[[aspect]] ~ Treatment, data = data)
  
  # Normality residuals as group
  qq <- ggqqplot(residuals(model))
  st <- shapiro_test(residuals(model))
  
  # Normality test by group
  qqfac <- ggqqplot(data, aspect, facet.by = "Treatment")
  spfac <- data %>%
    group_by(Treatment) %>%
    shapiro_test(!!sym(aspect))
  
  list = list(lt, qq, st, qqfac, spfac)
  return(list)
```